# Angularfire2 is it must?

Tags: angular, firebase, angularfire2

I want to build a site with angular and firebase.

I understand that angularfire2 is the official library for using angular and firebase.

The problem is that I found angularfire2 very not friendly and not documented well, especially compared to the firebase documentation.

Can I build the site without using angularfire2 or is it must?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After short test I can say that this is not must. I can use firebase directly without angularfire2.